# Executing a while loop while constantly checking sensor input

Tags: python, while-loop, raspberry-pi, sensors

what I'm trying to do is have my RC respond to user keystroke and then drive accordingly (forward, reverse, turn left and right, etc). However, I have also mounted a sensor at the front. I want to constantly measure that reading and if it's below a threshold, it break out of the loop and the program stops. I'm having trouble with constantly reading the sensor.

The program currently just get 1 reading when user enter a keystroke. Please help

```
d1 = distance()

while (d1 >= 20):  
   d1 = distance()

   if (d1 <= 20):
      drive("stop")

   char = getch()

   if (char == "w"):
      drive("forward")

   char""

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Is this on a rapsberry pi ?

Comment: HI marko, yes it is

Answer (score 0):

If `distance()` function is ok it should work

```
d1 = distance()

while (d1 >= 20):  
   d1 = distance()

   char = getch()

   if (char == "w"):
      drive("forward")

   char = "" #maybe this typo ? 

drive("stop") #there is no need for overlaping logic in case of 20 

GPIO.cleanup()
```

You will have to use different approach

```
from threading import Thread
import time
dist = 0 

def distance(): # your function for messurment 
    global dist
    dist = #your messurment, ..

Thread(target = distance).start()

time.sleep(1) #give it time to do some readings

while(dist >= 20):
   char = getch()
   if(char == "w"):
      drive("forward")

drive("stop")
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: hi Marko
the line
char = " "

just reset the keystroke and waits for the next keystroke, so if "w" was pressed, car would move forward, then reset that keystroke. If a use then type "s" it would reverse, etc

Comment: look at your code and look at my, that line is not even needed because char is only defined inside while loop, now what exactly is issue with your code

Comment: what getch library are you using, there are many holes in your question, so you need http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The problem with my code is that the program will get the distance reading once, before the while loop. So if the car was driving forward after user press "w" it would be completely blind because it is not getting the sensor reading inside the while loop.

Comment: what I need, is while the car is driving foward after user press "w" it continues to monitor the reading from distance() and stop when that reading fall below 20